# extract the data from a text file without any delimiter or spaces and append it two file different files

Tags: shell, unix

I have an input text file which appears like this,

```
12717251268292797123831987-->Header

a1921972998468104998676534716
17923862384623647864723467631
28791379370982379807821876843
23767891263716387928371836183
32189378913681698677676372876
28168961846349876479864210986

12541521---->tail
```

Now I want to  split the above file in to **two different** text files.

Can anyone suggest me how to do it using unix shell script.

Comment: any rule to follow to do the split? if there is no rule, you can create an empty file. that file with your original would be the two **different** text files.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
split -l 'number of lines' filename
```