# Extract data from one text file

Tags: shell, unix

sorry for creating confusion, i need a script and my requirement is if i am 
having text file which contains header,records & tail for 
eg:- Test1.txt (input File)
for example
i have a text file

### Input file

```
test1.txt   
---------   
2013101000490398938---HEADER
rohitroshankavuriM26single2010198702092013000(4053 characters each line contains)
rohitroshankavuriM26single2010198702092013000(4053 characters each line contains)
rohitroshankavuriM26single2010198702092013000(4053 characters each line contains)
rohitroshankavuriM26single2010198702092013000(4053 characters each line contains)
rohitroshankavuriM26single2010198702092013000(4053 characters each line contains)
201310100004005--TAIL
```

i need to write a UNIX shell script which will extract specific columns data from
input file based on their positions because i don't have delimiters or not even
spaces.And here i have to extract some columns(randomly i can pick based on their
positions) and save them to text file

for suppose eg: if i need a text file that should extract data from position
1-5,6-8,9,10-12  as shown and it should not contain header and tail.

```
normally i have used this script to

#Create as same as the input file    
cat Test1.txt>tmp.txt    
#here i will delete the header and tail from the tmp.txt file    
sed '1d,$d' tmp.txt    
#now i will extract the data based upon the    
cut 1-5,6-8,9,10-12 Test1.txt>Test2.txt
```

O/P will be like this
    Test2.txt
    ---------
    rohitroshank
    rohitroshank
    rohitroshank
    rohitroshank

Now my 1st output file is ready Test2.txt

### My Second requirement

now same output as 1st output file but here i can pick some different columns but it
should contains the data with header, records, tail
for eg:

To print first line which is header and after that i am having records and after
tail

```
Test3.txt(output file)      
--------------------------    
 #to print the head    
 head -1 tmp.txt>Test3.txt     
 #now i will pick specific columns based upon my positions & append it to test3.txt
 cut 13-15,16-19,20 tmp.txt>>Test3.txt    
 #print and append it to Test3.txt file     
 tail -1 tmp.txt>>Test.txt
```

### Output Test3.txt

2013101000490398938
avuriM26
avuriM26
avuriM26
avuriM26
avuriM26
avuriM26
avuriM26
201310100004005

Till now my requirement is completed But is there any other simple way to get this
    output.If yes please share me script so it will useful for me.

```
And but also now i am stuck with a problem i.e     
extracting specific columns data using CUT command.see any text file      
each line will contain 1024 characters but i have 4093 characters so how would i 
approach this requirement rather than doing it using CUT.

Is there any other way please suggest me. If are having any queries regarding my
requirement comment it here
```

Comment: your question is little confusing . I couldnt get what you mean.

Comment: Duplicate of your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310937/extract-the-data-from-a-text-file-without-any-delimiter-or-spaces-and-append-it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script file name is `special_copy.sh`, and you pass 3 parameters to it, named `test1.txt`, `test2.txt` and `test3.txt` as per your example, paste following to sh file:

```
head -n -1 $1 | tail -n +2 > $2
cp $1 $3
```

Then call it like `sh special_copy.sh test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt`.

Basically, it will read from `test1.txt`, copy all lines except first and last line to `test2.txt`, and simply copy the file with name `test3.txt`.

Comment: But i need to run to scripts every time, is there any other way it should run from one script all the process

Comment: I am confused here. There are only 2 steps that are required for creation of those 2 files and I have given you to create a shell script file and use this file. If this is not what you were looking for, please post complete question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -n +2 test1.txt | head -n -1 > test2.txt
cp test1.txt test2.txt
exit 0
```

Comment: write above code in any script say <DataExtract.sh> and run it :  sh DataExtract